# ckeditor for particular section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have a used case, where I have multiple text-areas on page. And unfortunately the name and id for these textareas are same. Actually it is tabbed section on the page.

I need to apply ckeditor to particular tab section, and not all.

```
CKEDITOR.replace('textarea');
```

replaces only the first textarea. However, I want to skip first and replace second or for another context I want to skip second and replace third and first textareas of same name.

Any idea?

Comment: So if we were to have code that would set the ids to be unique (like they should) would that be an issue? If not, how about replaceAll?

Comment: Actually, the it is a tabbed section. The tabs have different ID not the textareas. The textareas might have same ID or same name. Only the parent div will surely have different ID. 

And how to use replaceAll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All html elements are stored in an index . Try the following jquery funtion .eq() to grab a specific textarea .

Example .

```
var textArea1 = $("textarea");
```

then replace a specific textarea at any index in the dom..

```
// FYI grabing the 2nd <textarea> element on the page...

CKEDITOR.replace(textArea1.eq(1))
```

WORKING EXAMPLE HERE: http://codepen.io/theConstructor/pen/pyRXYa

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried something like this.

Each tabbed section has its own id or whaterver,

```
$('textarea.ckeditor').each(function() {
     CKEDITOR.replace(this);
});
```

And this worked fine for me!